# type mismatch; found : List[Double.type] required: List[Double]

Tags: scala

I'm trying to calculate average in scala this is my function average:

```
  def average(list: List[Double]): Double =
    list.foldLeft(0.0)(_ + _) / list.foldLeft(0.0)((r, c) => r + 1)
```

and this is my code:

```
    var p3 = List(Double)
    for (dimension <- result.dimensions) {
      p3 :+ dimension.average
    }
    println(average(p3))
```

My structure:

```
{
"result" : {
"dimensions" : [{
"average" : 2.2
},
{
"average" : 4.2
}]
} 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initialization of your empty `List` is wrong. Try the following instead:

```
var p3 = List[Double]()
```

Apart from that, you could achieve the same in an easier, more idiomatic way. One way is to use `yield`:

```
val p3 = for (dimension <- result.dimensions) yield dimension.average
```

Which is basically the same as just doing

```
val p3 = result.dimensions.map(_.average)
```

Apart from that, your average function is a bit complex, you can compute the average of a list just by doing `val avg = list.sum/list.length`.

Comment: thank you for uour replay but the result of your code gives seq and not a list

Comment: @Rajeun You can always obtain a `List` from a `Seq` by calling `toList` on it. If the underlying data structure already is a `List` (which is highly likely in your case), then there is no runtime overhead, it's just a cast internally.

Answer (score 1):

`List(Double)` is a list containing one element which is the so-called companion object of `Double`. If you want an empty list of `Double`, you need `List[Double]()` (or clearer, `List.empty[Double]`). Then the next error is that in the `p3 :+ dimension.average` you create a new `List` and then do nothing with it. You can fix it by using `p3 = p3 :+ dimension.average`, but that would be a horrible style.

Comment: @Rajeun `list.foldLeft(0.0)((r, c) => r + 1)` can be replaced with `list.size`. More readable and better performance.